# Can you reduce casting times in The Black Company magic system?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, campaign-settings

In [*The Black Company*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/48080/black-company)'s magic system, it is possible to increase the casting time of a spell in order to reduce its DC to cast. Is it possible to do the reverse, increasing the DC to make it faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

You can't simply revert the rule. There is nothing stating, that you could reduce the time, therefore you can't.